# Java - What is the RGB background and foreground color of DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter?

Tags: java

I want to know the RGB background and foreground color of the DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter in Java or any way of finding them.

Answer (score 0):

Download a color picking software, start your program, then use the color picker to find out.
e.g. [ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/)

Comment: I mean finding out programmatically.